# CodeIgniter - Delete data from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to delete data from 3 table,i have table `user`,`pemohon`,`peserta` where all table is connected each other with foreign key.

this query work,I've tried on mysql

```
DELETE user,pemohon,peserta
FROM user,pemohon,peserta
WHERE user.id_user=pemohon.id_pemohon AND
pemohon.id_pemohon=peserta.id_peserta AND pemohon.id_pemohon=1
```

so i convert to CodeIgniter like this

```
function delete_data($id)
{
    $this->db->where('pemohon.id_pemohon=user.id_user');
    $this->db->where('pemohon.id_pemohon=peserta.id_peserta');
    $this->db->where('pemohon.id_pemohon',$id);
    $this->db->delete('pemohon','user','peserta');
}
```

but this code not work, can you fix my code? Thanks

Comment: Fine. You can also use `$this->db->query("Put your query here which you run in mysql")`

Comment: @Nidhi i've tried it,$this->db->query("DELETE user,pemohon,peserta FROM user,pemohon,peserta WHERE user.id_user=pemohon.id_pemohon AND pemohon.id_pemohon=peserta.id_peserta AND pemohon.id_pemohon=$id"); but not work

Comment: but you told above `this query work` then Why it does not work?? .Try it with give static id `pemohon.id_pemohon=1` and also check `$id` have value or not?

Comment: if i use static id is work, but when i change to paramater `$id` the id not give the value,
but when i print `$id` it give value, i think i just can't Directly insert `$id` in `$this->db->query` is there any other way?

Comment: Are you tried to print `$id` in `delete_data` function ?? try this : $this->db->query("DELETE user,pemohon,peserta FROM user,pemohon,peserta WHERE user.id_user=pemohon.id_pemohon AND pemohon.id_pemohon=peserta.id_peserta AND pemohon.id_pemohon='".$id."'");`

Comment: yeah when i use `var_dump($id)` it give value `string(1) "7" `, i've tried this `pemohon.id_pemohon='".$id."'` but is not work

Comment: `echo "id is:".$id` in `delete_data` function insted in var_dump. print this.

Comment: yeah it same ,it's give the values id is: 7,but when i use in `this->db->query` the value Did not appear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In delete function you must be provide array of tables:

```
function delete_data($id)
{
    $this->db->where('pemohon.id_pemohon=user.id_user');
    $this->db->where('pemohon.id_pemohon=peserta.id_peserta');
    $this->db->where('pemohon.id_pemohon',$id);
    $this->db->delete(array('pemohon','user','peserta'));
}
```

If it not worked, execute with query function ($id escaped):

```
function delete_data($id)
{
    $sql = "DELETE user,pemohon,peserta 
        FROM user,pemohon,peserta 
        WHERE user.id_user=pemohon.id_pemohon 
        AND pemohon.id_pemohon=peserta.id_peserta 
        AND pemohon.id_pemohon= ?";

    $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
}
```

And without escaping $id:

```
function delete_data($id)
{
    $this->db->query("DELETE user,pemohon,peserta 
        FROM user,pemohon,peserta 
        WHERE user.id_user=pemohon.id_pemohon 
        AND pemohon.id_pemohon=peserta.id_peserta 
        AND pemohon.id_pemohon= $id";
}
```

Comment: As i see codeigniter documentation, this query cannot be execute with query builder and you can use `$this->db->query()` function.

Comment: Sorry i'm still newbie in codeigniter`AND pemohon.id_pemohon= ?`

Comment: Question marks filling by second parameter in `$this->db->query()` function, but it escaped for preventing sql injection.

Comment: if i insert parameter `$id` like this `pemohon.id_pemohon=$id' it not give value and if i insert parameter `$id` like this `pemohon.id_pemohon=array($id)' it's give the value array(7) but in array format. any other way?

Comment: `pemohon.id_pemohon=$id'` cannot replace $id with value, must be use double quotes start and end of string. at the end: `pemohon.id_pemohon=$id"`

Comment: can you give me example?
i've tried this `pemohon.id_pemohon='".$id."'` but is also not work

Comment: and this? `$this->db->query("DELETE user,pemohon,peserta FROM user,pemohon,peserta WHERE user.id_user=pemohon.id_pemohon AND pemohon.id_pemohon=peserta.id_peserta AND pemohon.id_pemohon= $id");`

Answer (score 2):

you can try this process

```
function delete_data($id)
{
   $this->db->delete('user', array('id_user' => $id)); 
   $this->db->delete('pemohon', array('id_pemohon' => $id));
   $this->db->delete('peserta', array('id_peserta' => $id));
}
```

Comment: if i use this code, it just deleted data from table `pemohon` but not deleted in other table

Answer (score 0):

You can save table name within an array and pass that array as parameter in delete(). As you can read full example : https://tutorialpace.com/CodeIgniter-Tutorials/CodeIgniter-Database-Delete